# ups calculation is wrong in asp.net app

Tags: c#, e-commerce, ups

I am not getting correct response from UPS when I am sending my response compared to the calculator they have online. 
Here is the link where you can see the data I am sending to UPS in XML Format: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4571235/example.xml

The results I am getting in my code are these: http://gyazo.com/70d494bf47c7c9864e2094471f15fea2.png?1339458514

And the results which I need to get (and I am getting when I am entering the same parameters online at UPS web): http://gyazo.com/f3b97ed3875ab80d3c4892a2275f6670.png?1339458571

Please let me know if I have something wrong in my xml doc or somewhere else.
Thanks, Laziale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your title - this has nothing to do with ASP.Net....

It's been a long time since I've integrated UPS but if memory serves, you should provide the same information in your request because they all matter in the calculation:

E.g.

1. Scheduled pickup or drop-off?
2. You didn't provide full address in your request, just a zip code, so `Residential Indicator` matters (a lot) - re: residential destination vs commercial destination
3. Are you being provided retail rates or your UPS account rates?

And so on.....

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<RatingServiceSelectionRequest xml:lang='en-US'>
```

To:

```
<RatingServiceSelectionRequest>
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't help. Thanks though

Comment: @Laziale post your code and I'll see what I can do.  Ideally post something I can cut/paste into a console app and run it to try out some things...

Comment: pls check the code for making the UPS request: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4571235/code.cs Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @Laziale You're asking for "bare bones" information, which means you want VERY little information...  "<CustomerContext>Bare Bones Rate Request</CustomerContext>" if what you have.  I don't have access to the Dev info page on UPS ATM, but change that to another value, perhaps just "Complex Rate Request", I don't know.  Check out the dev help page on UPS and find the value that you need/want.